# не получается решить задачу в javascript

Tags: javascript

Задача:
Все минимальные и максимальные значение поменять местами
     a = [5,7,1,2,7];
     b = [2,8,1,1,5];

Ответ: будет: a = [5,8,1,2,7]; b = [2,7,1,1,5];
Как это правильно изобразить в javascript'e?

Я новичок в этом деле, а решить надо. 
Наваял, так сказать начало, а вот как дальше обменять большее с меньшим не получается (

```
a=[5,7,1,2,7];
b=[2,8,1,1,5];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++)
        {
        if(a[i]>b[j]) 
        {
        a[i]=a[i]; 
        b[j]=b[j];
        }
            if(a[i]<b[j])
            {
            a[i]=b[j]; 
            b[j]=a[i];
            }
        }

document.write(a+"<br>"+b);
```

получается не то:
8,8,8,8,8
2,8,1,1,5

Comment: опишите логику Ваших (желательных) действий словами

Comment: 5 сравниваем с 2, если 5 больше 2, а оно больше, то 5=5 в 1ом массиве, а 2=2 во 2ом массиве.  Далее 7 сравниваем с 8, то в 1ом массиве становиться 7, т.к. 8 больше 7, а 2ом массиве становится 8 по условию задачи. И т.д.

Comment: достаточно найти максимальный и минимальный элемент в каждом массиве, а дальше поменять местами их по `indexOf`

Comment: Из формулировки задачи не вполне ясно, почему `a` в результате должен быть именно `[5,8,1,2,7]`, а не `[5,8,1,2,8]`. Сказано же, "все максимальные значения", а их в исходном массиве `a` два.

Comment: я в начале программирования, IndexOf еще не проходили

Comment: @Dima - ну при чем здесь 5 и 2? Логику, логику опишите.

Comment: @ Yaant точно. Должно быть [5,8,1,2,8] Т.е. меняем большие значения из а (это 7) на 8.     
a=[5,7,1,2,7];
b=[2,8,1,1,5];
maxa=a[0];
maxb=b[0];
temp=0;

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 if(a[i]>maxa) maxa=a[i];
   
for(j=0;j<b.length;j++)
 if(b[j]>maxb) maxb=b[j];
    
maxa[b]=a[i];
maxa[a]=b[j];
  
   
document.write(a+"<br>"+b);

Answer (score 0):

Вспомогательная функция:

```js
function findMinMax(anArray) {
  var result = {
    iMin: -1,
    vMin: null,
    iMax: -1,
    vMax: null
  };
  if (anArray.length > 0) {
    result.iMin = result.iMax = 0;
    result.vMin = result.vMax = anArray[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < anArray.length; i++) {
      if (anArray[i] < result.vMin) {
        result.iMin = i;
        result.vMin = anArray[i];
      }
      if (anArray[i] > result.vMax) {
        result.iMax = i;
        result.vMax = anArray[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var a = [5, 7, 1, 2, 7];
var b = [2, 8, 1, 1, 5];

var r1 = findMinMax(a);
var r2 = findMinMax(b);
console.log(r1);
console.log(r2);
```

Comment: Igor, спасибо, возможно это правильное решение, но я пока на самом начале, и этот код сложен. Прошли только 6 видов циклов и 1 уровненные массивы.

Comment: @Dima это еще не решение, мы к нему только приближаемся. Разберитесь в этом коде, задайте вопросы, если что-то непонятно, потом пойдем дальше.

Comment: вчитался в условия задачи. из массива а нужно найти большие и заменить их на большие из массива b. т.е. 7 на 8.

Comment: @Dima хорошо. Вам понятно, что делает функция `findMinMax`?

Comment: большее в а, и большее в b я с помощью кода я нашел. осталось правильно заменить. for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 if(a[i]>maxa) 
  {
  maxa=a[i];
  }
  alert(maxa);
   
for(j=0;j<b.length;j++)
 if(b[j]>maxb)
  {
  maxb=b[j];
  }
  alert(maxb);

Comment: @Dima идете в цикле по массиву `а`. Если элемент равен `maxa`, меняете его на `maxb`. Аналогично - для массива `b`.

Comment: грусть печаль, я в тупике, не могу поменять местами (

Comment: @Dima покажите, как Вы это делаете